# Mouse clicks stop working after attempting a screenshot in Chrome

Tags: gnome, 20.04, mouse, google-chrome

This happens after trying to take a cropped screenshot (Shift + Print) when a drop-down element (`<select>`) is open in Chrome. Can be reproduced in [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) - click on the "Choose a car" select, then hit Shift + Print.

Mouse still works and moving it affects windows' focus.

I tried various solutions / checks from existing answers:

- Reloading the `psmouse` module
- `xev` shows no input events for clicks
- `evtest` shows events for clicks
- Switching to another TTY, then back (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448898/387108))

The issue remains. Restarting `gdm3` helped, but at the cost of restarting my session, so it's equivalent to a restart... (which helps as well, obviously)

Specs:

- Dell XPS 7590 15"
- GNOME Shell 3.36.3-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
- Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116
- `xserver-xorg-core` 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1

Comment: I noticed that resetting Gnome with Alt + F2 -> R -> Enter helps.

Comment: Killing gnome-shell helped me. Described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1298813/312150

Comment: Just to add to @Jong comment: Alt + F2 -> r -> Enter, so r shouldbe lowercase. Otherwise thanks a lot for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

gnome-shell reset works!

Alt + F2 -> r -> Enter

You may try to hotkey:
`dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'`

Comment: Thanks, I always have this issue, and have always had to restart my PC! This works.